# How do I dynamically create file download links in code behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have files on the web server. I want to make them available for download to a client. However, I don't know what the files will be, or even how many there will be until runtime. If I create a hyperlink with the NavigateUrl set to the file location on the server, then the client just tries to locate the file on their local system at that location, so that doesn't work. I was able to get a single file to work using a linkbutton, but that is also not an option because I can't create it dynamically.

Is there a way to do this dynamically in ASP.NET?

Comment: Could you set the `NavigateUrl` property dynamically?

Comment: As I mentioned, I can change the NavigateUrl, but then when the user clicks on it, it just tries to navigate to that URL on their local machine. I need them to be able to download files from a directory on the server.

Comment: Sounds like you are putting "localhost" in the `NavigateUrl`. You need to substitute the externally visible domain name that resolves to the IP address of your web server. Or you can try making it a relative URL if the resource is on the same server.

Comment: Well, links have an url... I can't see what's the problem with this. What you could do is replace them with a `LinkButton` and manage the download from server side, pushing the bytes of the file to the response, but you already said that you can't use `LinkButton` either. Another option is to write an `HttpHandler` to serve the files. Then you could replace the "url" for whatever you need. Can you please explain in more detail the problem?

Comment: The problem I was having is that I couldn't figure out how to handle the clicks on the links. I've posted the solution I eventually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I eventually solved this was to use a repeater and then put the action in the repeater instead of in the link button.

```
<asp:Repeater id="repLinks" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repLinks_OnItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then the code behind as follows:

```
protected void repLinks_OnItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
    Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Current.Response.WriteFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(_path, e.CommandArgument.ToString))
    Current.Response.Flush()
    Current.Response.[End]()
}
```

The thing I was missing is that I could have the same handler for every LinkButton in the repeater, and then just pass the filename as a CommandArgument.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the files from the server and display them in a Repeater Control

```
//the relative folder path
string folder = "/images";

//read all the files in the folder
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(folder));
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();

//bind to a Repeater
Repeater1.DataSource = files;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And then on the aspx page

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                     NavigateUrl='<%# "/images/" + Eval("Name") %>'><%# Eval("Name") %>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Comment: That puts the names in a list of links, but how do I actually have the links download the files?

Comment: With this `"/images/" + Eval("Name")`

Comment: That still only makes a local link. The client evaluates that by trying to go to that directory on the client's machine. I actually found a solution, which I will post in an answer.